# Django2 - automatically assign certain amount of cryptocurrency to user signing up

Tags: python, django, model

Good morning,

We are currently working on a school project where we have to built our own cryptocurrency market. So far so good.

Now, when a user registers/signs up on our site he automatically get's a certain amount of one specific cryptocurrency. This is considered as being a transaction between the Bank and the created user.

We have our custom sign up form and believe that the code that we need for this feature has to be implemented there, but don't know how this has to be done.

Thank you very much for your help

Our sign up form in the views.py

```
#signup form
def signup(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            #We want to log in the user after his sign up
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'sign-up.html', {'SignUpForm': form})
```

Our transaction model. We use the django user model

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    listing_id = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    exchange_amount = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    user_debit = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_debit', null=True)
    user_credit = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_credit', null=True)
    currency_id = models.ForeignKey(Currency, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Comment: Random amount of random currency? Or a specific amount of a random currency? Or a specific amount of a specific currency?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. Let's stick to specific amount of a specific currency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a transaction during the registration. I'm assuming the bank is also a (currency dependant?) user, say with id=1. Then something like,

```
from django.db import transaction

#signup form
def signup(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #atomic makes sure that the changes are only commited if the entire block of code is succesfully completed
            with transaction.atomic():
                new_user = form.save()
                transaction_signup = Transaction(
                    user_debit = new_user,
                    user_credit = get_user_model().objects.get(id=1),
                    exchange_amount = 1,
                    currency_id = Curreny.objects.get(id=3)
                )
                transaction_signup.save()
                #We want to log in the user after his sign up
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'sign-up.html', {'SignUpForm': form})
```

would work. You don't however HAVE to do this in your view. You can for example use [post save signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#post-save).

Comment: Thanks

When I try to signup and click on the submit button I now get this error message: local variable 'transaction' referenced before assignment.

Comment: I'm guessing that's a funny coincidence with the naming combined with the use of transaction.atomic(). I changed the name of the variable, this should fix it.